# IOS passbook code example how to add?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I simply trying to add my passbook without sharing via email. How i can add my passbook on click button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code assumes that you know how to create the pass in the first place...

```
NSError * passerror;

PKPass * pass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:data error:&passerror];

if(!pass) {
    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pass Failed" message:@"Sorry there was a problem creating your Passbook." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    return;
}

//init a pass library
PKPassLibrary* passLib = [[PKPassLibrary alloc] init];

//check if pass library contains this pass already
if([passLib containsPass:pass]) {

    //pass already exists in library, show an error message
    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pass Exists" message:@"Pass is already in Passbook." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

} else {

    //present view controller to add the pass to the library
    PKAddPassesViewController *vc = [[PKAddPassesViewController alloc] initWithPass:pass];
    [vc setDelegate:(id)self];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**EDIT** You'll need to import

```
#import <PassKit/PassKit.h>
```

Comment: What i need to import?